# Algorithm pseudocode

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

I have the pseudocode:

```
Algorithm exists(A,n,x):
     lo=0
     hi=n-1
     while hi>=lo:
        mid=floor((hi+lo)/2):
        if x>A[mid]: 
          lo=mid+1
        else: if x<A[mid]:
           hi=mid-1
        else:
           return True
     return False
```

and the array:
 `A[0]=1, A[1]=5, A[2]=6, A[3]=10, A[4]=12, A[5]=16, A[6]=17, A[7]=43`

Then I have to find what exists(A,4,17) return.

Then we have `l0=0` and `hi=n-1=4-1=3` then `hi>l0`.

We get that `mid=floor((hi+lo)/2)=floor((3+0)/2)=1` (floor is rounding to `1`?).

We see that `x<A[1]` because `4<5`. Then I think the pseudocode return: `hi=mid-1=1-1=0`?

Comment: Please don't show images of text, copy-paste (if possible) or write the text *as text* into the question itself. Please [edit] your question to improve it. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Sorry. I normally study math. So I don't know how this site work

Comment: Well that's what the links in my comments are for, to help you learn about this site and how it works and how to write good questions.

Comment: Thank you, I think it is better now

Answer (score 1):

The code you have written, it is binary search pseudocode. Through binary search, you can search for a number in a sorted array.

In your code, your explanation is wrong. Let me explain why.

Your array: `A[0]=1`, `A[1]=5`, `A[2]=6`, `A[3]=10`, `A[4]=12`, `A[5]=16`, `A[6]=17`,`A[7]=43`

Then you want to found `exists(A,4,17)`, according to your algorithm,

`A resembles your array`, `n=4`, `x=17`

So, according to this your explanation in the last line is wrong because after the first iteration the `mid=1` and then it will execute  `if x>A[mid]:` condition because,

```
17 > 5 //as x=17 and A[1]= 5
```